# Can you use animated images as symbols in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, symbology

How is it possible to use image that blink or change (animate) as 
symbol in mapinfo? I tried to create custom symbol that blink in 
mapinfo but after I added it as symbol it didn't blink. Have I done 
something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use animated gifs as symbols Kitex, and I assume this is what you are trying to use.  Once you import them, and use them, they simply become gifs.